# How do you check if a file exist locally with an electron app

Tags: javascript, bash, electron, exec

I am trying to see if a file exists locally like this:

```
if (exec(`-f ~/.config/myApp/bookmarks.json`)) {
  console.log('exists')
} else {
  console.log('does not')
}
```

However, I get **exists** in the console whether the file exists or not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should import the `fs` module into your code.
If you're running on the `main`process, then do a simple `const fs = require('fs');` but if you're on the renderer process then run `const fs = require('electron').remote.require('fs')`

Then with the `fs` module you can run a simple exists method on the file:

```
if (fs.existsSync(`~/.config/myApp/bookmarks.json`)) {
  console.log('exists')
} else {
  console.log('does not')
}
```

Although you really should check for this asynchronously:

```
fs.access(`~/.config/myApp/bookmarks.json`, (err) => {
  if (err) {
      console.log('does not exist')
    } else {
      console.log('exists')
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm getting this output in the console when the file does exist:  err Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '~/.config/stud/gui/bookmarks.json'

Comment: FYI, I am using your asynchronous solution. Could it be that config is a hidden file?

Comment: You should only get that if you actually print out the error.

Comment: Sorry, I am. That's what I meant. I'm just wanted to know of there was an error, and what it was.

Comment: so interestingly enough, if I put the actual path, and not the ~ it is able to find the file. This however won't work for me

Comment: @ss_matches Node's `fs` doesn't recognize `~`. Try `path.join(os.homedir(), <yourpath>)` to resolve your path. (you'll need to `require("path"); require("os");`)

Comment: why would you need `const fs = require('electron').remote.require('fs')` in renderer process? `const fs = require('fs')` should work there too (unless node integration is turned off)

Comment: Any pointers how to do this (use the fs) in the renderer process?